# rails one-to-many assocaition not saving record on db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

**shop.rb**

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :earning_rules
end
```

**earning_rules.rb**

```
class EarningRule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shop

  scope :order_rule, lambda {
    where(status: 'true').where(name: 'Order').where(shop_id: shop.id)
  }

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :point, presence: true

  def set_shop
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: current_shopify_domain)
    self.shop = shop.id
  end
end
```

**earning_rules_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @earning_rule = current_user.earning_rules.new(earning_rule_params)
    @earning_rule.set_shop

    respond_to do |format|
      if @earning_rule.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Earning rule was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @earning_rule }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @earning_rule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def earning_rule_params
    params.require(:earning_rule).permit(:user_id, :shop_id, :name, :point, :status)
  end
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for earning_rule do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :point %>
  <%= f.check_box :status, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-info btn-sm float-right ml-auto' %>
<% end %>
```

**Log**

```
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.490569 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9] Processing by EarningRulesController#create as HTML
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.490699 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"/BrJVX8bilaCc7yw/Hs0ngLh8O0DixA5lePv8bbLR1vpOBZ2MxBlk+qq7BCcM2xEh/XU8UjF6rWXUmZ1HQMf1Q==", "earning_rule"=>{"name"=>"nn", "point"=>"5", "status"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Earning rule"}
D, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.492421 #92642] DEBUG -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   Shop Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.493549 #92642] DEBUG -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.499620 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   Rendering earning_rules/new.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.507452 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   Rendered earning_rules/_form.html.erb (Duration: 7.1ms | Allocations: 2097)
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.507994 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   Rendered earning_rules/new.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app (Duration: 8.2ms | Allocations: 2223)
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.508949 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 179)
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.509206 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9]   Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 87)
I, [2019-11-20T09:42:01.509606 #92642]  INFO -- : [96fe8592-245a-4537-8771-69a8261859e9] Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 10.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 4864)
```

I dont know what I am missing. shop_id data is not in the log parameter and this works before I added shop associations. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no shop field in your form. You can add a hidden tag with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: current_shopify_domain)
self.shop = shop.id
```

I bet current_shopify_domain is not defined, so that the shop cannot be found. Also, your column is probably called shop_id? Add validation rules for the presence of user_id and shop_id in order to have Rails inform you of what's missing.

If that doesn't help, try creating an EarningRule in the console in order to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Absolutely. After I debugged with binding.pry. I figured out `current_shopify_domain` is not defined hence the 422 Unprocessable Entity error.